# Browsing on Apple TV without mirroring?

Tags: keyboard

I wonder if its possible to browser websites on Apple TV without having an iPod, iPhone or iPad to mirror from.

If Apple TV has a browser that I can use with my Bluetooth keyboard, that would be awesome. Is it possible yet?

Edited to Add: I haven't jailbroken my ATV yet, but I'm open to any solution that requires it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no browser app for Apple TV itself. The best I've found so far is [Airweb](https://itunes.apple.com/ch/app/web-browser-fur-apple-tv/id770893993?mt=8) which of course still requires an iOS device. But it's easier to use than a mirrored Safari.

Comment: Ah, not possible even on jailbroken devices?

Comment: Don't know about jailbroken ATVs. If you are open for such solutions it might be worth to mention this in the question.